# How to retrieve only tweets about a hashtag within an hour?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter

I have been trying to write a python code to use snscrape to retrieve tweets about a hashtag within an hour. But my code has been returning an empty dataframe each time I tried.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
now = datetime.utcnow()
since = now - timedelta(hours=1)
```

```
since_str = since.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
until_str = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')

# Query tweets with hashtag #SOSREX in the last one hour
query = '#SOSREX Since:' + since_str + ' until:' + until_str
SOSREX_data = []
```

```
SOSREX_data=[]
for tweet in sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper(query).get_items():
    if len(SOSREX_data)>100:
        break
    else:
        SOSREX_data.append([tweet.date,tweet.user.username,tweet.user.displayname,
                            tweet.content,tweet.likeCount,tweet.retweetCount,
                            tweet.sourceLabel,tweet.user.followersCount,tweet.user.location
                           ])
    
# Creating a dataframe from the tweets list above 
Tweets_data = pd.DataFrame(SOSREX_data, 
                         columns=["Date_tweeted","username","display_name", 
                                  "Tweets","Number_of_Likes","Number_retweets",
                                  "Source_of_Tweet",
                                  "number_of_followers","location"
                                 ])
print("Tweets_data")
```

Comment: I think, due to the whitespace, you have to quote escape the time strings: `query = '#SOSREX Since:"' + since_str + '"' + ' until:"' + until_str + '"'`, or `query = f'#SOSREX Since:"{since_str}" until:"{until_str}"'`

Comment: But please don't post the same question multiple times.